# Who is the wealthiest wizard in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, money

Economics in the *Harry Potter* world is weird, not least because there's a single bank controlling all the money.

But who has (or needs) the biggest chamber at Gringotts? **Who is the richest wizard?**

Comment: if "Wit beyond measure is a man's greatest treasure" then that changes the math a bit ;)

Comment: The biggest chamber doesn't mean the richest wizard.

Comment: Nicolas Flamel has philosopher's stone, it can turn lead to gold.

Comment: [The result is that they {the Malfoys} are one of the richest wizarding families in Britain, and it has been rumoured for many years (though never proven) that over the centuries the family has dabbled successfully in Muggle currency and assets.](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-malfoy-family)

Comment: Gringotts isn't the only bank in the world. It's the only bank in Britain.

Comment: @Valorum But would that be her answer based on the information already present or just her deciding at that moment who the richest is?

Comment: By the end of DH Bellatrix is dead (we don't know who inherits from her) and we don't know what sort of fines payed/assets seizured (if any) the Malfoys got after the  end of the 2nd wizarding war. I believe Harry inherited all the contents of Sirius's vault

Comment: @Oni had* the stone is supposed to be detroyed after the first book

Comment: https://www.therichest.com/rich-list/the-5-richest-hogwarts-graduates/

Comment: The Goblins think all money is theirs...

Comment: @TheAsh It's odd that list places the Black family above the Malfoys. Lucius owns a mansion with surrounding gardens in Wiltshire, while the Blacks live in a fancy townhome. This isn't totally indicative of wealth but it could imply the Malfoys are the wealthiest wizards in the HP universe.

Comment: At least the hp universe that we know of currently.

Comment: The Malfoy's are the most obvious answer. They are certainly upper class.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly obvious answer of who the richest wizard is might be **Bellatrix Lestrange**, as in **Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows**, we can see how much stuff she has in her vault. However the true answer is shown all the way back in the **Philosophiser's Stone** (or the Sorcerer's Stone for Americans), and that is the Philosopher himself- **Nicolas Flamel**.
In chapter 13 of the book, Harry, Hermione and Ron complete their search for any mention of Flamel in the library, finding a book that tells them all about him.

> “**Nicolas Flamel**,” [Hermione] whispered dramatically, “is the only known maker of the **Philosopher's Stone**!”

And later on in the chapter:

> The ancient study of **alchemy** is concerned with making the
> **Philosopher’s Stone**, a legendary substance with astonishing powers. The stone will **transform any metal into pure gold**. It also
> produces the **Elixir of Life**, which will make the drinker immortal.
> There have been many reports of the **Philosopher’s Stone** over the
> centuries, but the only Stone currently in existence belongs to **Mr.
> Nicolas Flamel**, who celebrated his six hundred and sixty-fifth
> birthday last year, enjoys a quiet life in Devon with his wife,
> Perenelle (six hundred and fifty-eight).

The fact that the stone will ***transform any metal into pure gold*** makes it obvious that as he is the only living owner of a philosopher's stone, he is likely the richest.

Here's some more info about Flamel and his journey to making the stone: https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/the-real-nicolas-flamel-and-the-philosophers-stone

Comment: None of those are canon sources of info about the wealthiest wizards. They're just the wealthiest that the books talk about, and even then there's scanty evidence *which* is the wealthiest.

Comment: And as per my objection to all the other (now deleted) answers, these clickbait magazine articles all rely on quoting selectively from the books, then extrapolating wildly.

Comment: I've deleted the article link as what you said is true

Comment: I fail to see how having *the ability* to make gold makes Flamel the richest wizard. At best, bearing in mind that he seems to live relatively modestly, you could argue that *if he wanted to be the richest, he could be*

Comment: There's no evidence to point towards anyone else to be the richest and also I said it is likely he is the richest not definately

Comment: Also the question is *"Who's the wealthiest"*, not "name some wealthy wizards". Bellatrix is certainly wealthy, but can you show an iota of proof  that she's the **most** wealthy?

Comment: I never said she is I said that that would be a fairly obvious answer because of the amount of gold and other valuables in her bank vault

Comment: Her vault just demonstrates that she has a lot of wealth. Who's to say that the next vault over isn't even more fabulously full of gold?

Comment: Ok but i'm giving an answer based on the evidence there is not a random guess